# Which JS file to be included to use the function of dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, include

I want to open a dialog box for confirmation on click of a button. 
For that I am using the following code

```
$('#dialog-box').dialog({
                show : 'drop',
```

....

where #dialog-box is an ID for button. Now I am getting an error: 
**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'**

Which js File need to be included so that this error is removed

Comment: You'll need to post the section of your html which has #dialog-box

Answer (score 1):

The [`.dialog()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) function is part of [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started).

[Here's a library from Google's CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery-ui).
To make sure that you get everything that you need for JQuery UI, you can download it from [here](http://jqueryui.com/download)
or use their online hosted scripts from [here](http://code.jquery.com/).

[Here's a sample script](http://jsfiddle.net/3neQC/)

Note the order in which I retrieve the libraries and then execute the script:

1. JQuery
2. JQuery UI
3. Initialize dialog box

```html
<!-- JQuery UI stylesheet --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<!-- First get JQuery -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Then get JQuery UI -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog-box" ).dialog({
            width: "auto",
            height: "auto"
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="dialog-box" title="Getting down with dialog boxes">
    <p>This is how you initialize and use the dialog box.</p>
</div>
```