# Making a jQuery ui dialog not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, javascript

I have some code here that's supposed to produce a dialog box using the jquery ui.

CSS

```
        body { font: normal normal normal 10px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

    .ui-dialog-osx {
        -moz-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
        border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px; border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
    }
```

LIBRARIES

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
```

JS

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    draggable: true,
    resizable: true,
    position: ['center', 'top'],
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'blind',
    width: 400,
    dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
    buttons: {
        "I've read and understand this": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

HTML

Hello World!

```
<div id="dialog-message" title="Important information">
    <span class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 0 0;"></span></span>
    <div style="margin-left: 23px;">
        <p>
            We're closed during the winter holiday from 21st of December, 2010 until 10th of January 2011.
            <br /><br />
            Our hotel will reopen at 11th of January 2011.<br /><br />
            Another line which demonstrates the auto height adjustment of the dialog component.
        </p></div>
</div>
```

I actually found it on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreadwarrior/3d7QC/12/) using Google. I noticed that the fiddle is using jQuery 1.5.2 but I don't have that library (I download them so I can code offline). This code doesn't work for me on my local browser even though it works for fiddle. When I change the library the fiddle uses to jQuery 1.11.0 (which is the one I have in my laptop locally), the fiddle fails.

I was thinking if I have the latest jQuery version, that would be enough to support the new features? Or do I need to download this library separately?

When I look at the console for errors, there are no errors. So there's that out of the way.

What's the problem here?

Comment: Why including two version of jQuery ?? And why including both `.custom.min.js` and `.custom.js`.Include only one in each case .

Comment: Duplicate of question?> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024775/which-js-file-to-be-included-to-use-the-function-of-dialog

Comment: The jquery-1.11.0 is the one I use, but when I downloaded the ui library, it included the jquery-1.10.2. At first I didn't include both but when it didn't work, I tried to see what would happen if I included both

Comment: I had a problem where my dialog was working in Dev but not production... everything looked ok but i noticed i had old versions of JQuery and JQueryUI in my scripts folder... deleted these and it now works... might help someone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to include `jQuery` and `jQueryUI` once instead of twice like what you're doing at this moment:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
```

and also wrap your code inside DOM ready handler:

```
$(function() {
     // Your jQuery code here
});
```

Comment: don't forget to add <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

Comment: This answer and comment helped me. I removed the double includes for jquery and the ui and, added the ready handler. It now works. Also I found I had a css code and images I needed to include in the actual folder I was using. Thanks!